# Request to onedrive item for adding permission is giving Internal Server Error or Bad Request on some valid email Ids

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

`POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/invite`

**Request Body:**

```
{
    "recipients":[{"email":"some_valid@ID.com"}],
    "message":"",
    "requireSignIn":true,
    "sendInvitation":false,
    "roles":["write"]
}
```

**Response Body:**

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "The request is malformed or incorrect.",
        "innerError": {
              "request-id": "9031d868-5971-4b52-a15e-400e1e6f38be",
              "date": "2018-02-21T09:31:36"
          }
    }
}
```

This request is returning a `500 ("Internal server error")` or sometimes a `400 ("Bad Request")` with same data.

Also with some email Ids request is returning a `504 ("Gateway Timeout")` on the first call but in the second call it returning `200 ("OK")`.

Comment: Could you be more specific than "sometimes" and "some emails"?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur,
some emails only, For some email Ids this call is returning either 500 or 400 all the time.